# Show mounted btrfs subvolumes?

Tags: btrfs

Is there a command to show which btrfs subvolumes are mounted on each mountpoint?

Alternatively, is there somewhere (e.g. in the `/proc` or `/sys` trees) where the information can be read?

The output from the `df` command simply shows the filesystem's root device and `/etc/mtab` (aka `/proc/mounts`) doesn't contain the `subvol=...` option.

Comment: excellent!  mount doesn't contain the `subvol=...` option, either.

Comment: @user1902689: I don't understand your comment. If I mount a btrfs subvolume using `mount -tbtrfs -osubvol=home,compress=zlib,autodefrag,recovery /dev/sdc /home` then `/etc/mtab` contains a line `/dev/sdc /home btrfs rw,relatime,compress=zlib,space_cache,autodefrag,recovery 0 0`. The `subvol=...` option isn't included. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`findmnt -nt btrfs`, the source subvolume is in `[...]`, the mountpoint is the first column. Alternatively, you could look into the file `/proc/self/mountinfo` yourself.

Comment: thanks! - didn't know about `findmnt`.  (I use `mount | grep btrfs` per answer below.)

Comment: Thanks. For those like me that land here via google looking for a way to just list the mountpoints using btrfs, just add the `--output TARGET` parameter: `findmnt -nt btrfs --output TARGET`

Answer (score 5):

On older systems that don't have the nicely-formatted findmnt command, just run mount with no arguments.  It will spit out a list of devices, mountpoints, types and options.  Pipe it to grep for btrfs if you want to filter it down for easy reading.